# Does terms-lookup-filter aggregation order in elasticsearch query affect the execution time (efficiency)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following elasticsearch query with terms-lookup-filter aggregation. Both queries will give the same result. Both queries have same filter type only the difference is order (place) of terms-lookup-filter.

1.Here terms-lookup filter is in 2nd/last position of **and** filter aggregation.

```
  {
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "filterAggs": {
         "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "eligibleDates": {
                           "include_lower": true,
                           "include_upper": true,
                           "from": <fromDate>,
                           "to": <toDate>
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "rollNo": {
                           "path": "student.rollNo",
                           "index": "<index_name>",
                           "id": "<record_id>",
                           "type": "<es Type>"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

2.Here terms-lookup filter is in 1st position of **and** filter aggregation.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "filterAggs": {
         "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "rollNo": {
                           "path": "student.rollNo",
                           "index": "<index_name>",
                           "id": "<record_id>",
                           "type": "<es Type>"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "eligibleDates": {
                           "include_lower": true,
                           "include_upper": true,
                           "from": <fromDate>,
                           "to": <toDate>
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In my experiment/test, 1st query executes more efficiently (7 to 10 times faster) than the second one.
 Now my question is, Does terms-lookup-filter aggregation order in elasticsearch query affect the execution time (efficiency)?  How will the filter place order affect execution time?

Answer (score 0):

**No** It doesn't matter because **elasticsearch would find the optimized execution order** by specific algorithms.
I've seen in some articles they say you should order the filters/queries by some critera (e.g. which one is more filtery should go first) but after reading a very detailed and exact article found out they are **not correct**.
This is  great article about filter/query execution order in elasticsearch:

**[In which order are my Elasticsearch queries/filters executed?](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order?ultron=may-2017&blade=newsletter&hulk=email&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTkdNeFpETXpORFEyTXprNCIsInQiOiJhekpuVlFDelpOTGVreEpsWDBGNlZIXC9pU05KM0JZVFhvK2hxSVo4YjFoXC9FV1ZlU2ptRmhibG1XVGJXOWxVSVN3VkFXcW5jYTZKaVpUSDRjRXdmZ3RINGV2Z1ZPYzVWWmFrMDJOelBoY0tuUWJFSGVNVlJIamZGMWJiVm55R3AzIn0%3D)**

If you want to optimize your query I will suggest you to read this:

**[Optimizing Elasticsearch Searches](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-optimizing-elasticsearch-search)**

For example you have `range filter` and it could be optimized using the `Cache Granularity and Acceleration Filters` part.